# Can I connect a USB-C (Thunderbolt) dock to a USB-A PC? (re: USB 2.0 peripherals)

Tags: usb, usb-c, docking-station, thunderbolt

I'm using a CalDigit TS4 Thunderbolt dock with a few USB 2.0 peripherals connected (keyboard, mouse, etc).

Is it possible to connect the USB-C output to a USB-A PC?  (ie. Raspberry Pi)

I know that Alt Mode won't work (obviously) but I'm wondering if I can still use the dock as a simple USB hub (keyboard/mouse)?  Will this work or will I damage something?

Comment: Which RPI are we talking about? The RPI4 uses USB-C for power.

Comment: I'm referring to the RPi4 but I believe the USB-C power connector is only for power so I'm not talking about that.  I'm talking about connecting the dock to any of the USB-A ports on the RPI(4).